# Reading/Writing out a dictionary to csv file in python

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

Pretty new to python, and the documentation for csv files is a bit confusing.

I have a dictionary that looks like the following:

```
key1: (value1, value2)

key2: (value1, value2)

key3: (value1, value2)
....
```

I would like to write these out to a csv file in the format where each line contains the key, followed by the two values.

I would also like to be able to read them back into a dictionary from the file at a later date.

Comment: Read this https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/, try to solve it on your own, come here (if you have trouble) to ask specific questions.

Comment: Why a CSV? If you want to save and load you can look into things like `pickle` or `json`. Both have pretty solid dump and load methods, `json` outbut being user readable.

Comment: I will be using these values in excel to do some calculations on. But will be used across multiple files so that I can keep a running total.

Comment: Provide some code and then provide an example of what you want the output to look like.  I think I can see it but not totally sure.  Further, as already noted, this may not be best suited for the csv module.  Your structure is not a real natural for both reading and writing without knowing a lot about your data.  So specifically you will not be able to read it back into a dictionary without manipulation.  We use csv.DictWriter and csv.DictReader  but too do so we have to make sure our data is structured as a list of dictionaries, the keys are the cheadings and the values are the cell contents

Comment: a) **Are `value1, value2` numbers, or strings**, in which case when you say you want output `key: value1, value2`, they might need to be quoted (so internal commas don't get misinterpreted) and possibly escaped (so that internal newlines don't get misinterpreted) b) When you say you want to **write it out such that it could be read back as a dict**, do you mean as `key, value1, value2` such that the code has to know it's intended for a dict, or standard format that say's it's a dict like `key: value1, value2` , such as `pandas.to_csv` will write?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I didn't find enough benefit to use Pandas here since the problem is simple.

Also note to OP, if you want to store values to a file just for reading it back simply use JSON or Python's shelve module. Exporting to CSV should be minimised only when we need to interact potentially Excel users.

The below code converts a dict into CSV

```
value1 = 'one'
value2 = 'two'
d = { 
        'key1': (value1, value2), 
        'key2': (value1, value2), 
        'key3': (value1, value2)
    }
CSV ="\n".join([k+','+','.join(v) for k,v in d.items()]) 
#You can store this CSV string variable to file as below
# with open("filename.csv", "w") as file:
    # file.write(CSV)
```

This code explains what happens inside the list comprehension.

```
CSV = ""
for k,v in d.items():
    line = "{},{}\n".format(k, ",".join(v))
    CSV+=line
print CSV
```

Comment: This looks more like something I can comprehend. So where you have written "for k,v in d.items()", does the v parameter (assuming label for value) automatically pick up that there are 2 values (a tuple) there?

i.e will this print key,value1,value2?

Comment: Yes, the `v` is assumed for a tuple, `",".join` means join those tuple varialbes with a comma. I have elaborated the list comprehension with a for-loop. Hope that will be easier and more readable.

Answer (score 48):

I highly recommend [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) for this.

Convert to Pandas DataFrame:

```py
import pandas as pd

d = {
    'a': (1, 101),
    'b': (2, 202),
    'c': (3, 303)
}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient="index")
```

Create a CSV file:

```py
df.to_csv("data.csv")
```

Read the CSV file back as a DataFrame:

```py
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv", index_col=0)
```

Convert the DataFrame back to the original dictionary format:

```py
d = df.to_dict("split")
d = dict(zip(d["index"], d["data"]))
```

EDIT: Since you mention that your goal to use the output file in Excel, Pandas [to_excel()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) and [read_excel()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html) might be more useful to you since they better-preserve the content between conversions.
Also, you might want skip Excel altogether and use the [standard Python scientific stack](http://www.scipy.org/about.html#the-scipy-stack).

Comment: the good way using pandas is to_csv, no need for open command, cf my answer.

Comment: Don't want to sound picky, but does anyone know how to do it with just using naked python? Don't really want to be using other packages as a beginner of python.

Comment: If you are looking for something more minimal in terms of dependencies, then itsneo's answer is probably what you are aiming for.

Comment: I prefer this answer than the selected answer.

Comment: Using `index=False` maybe helpful for most users.

Answer (score 7):

I would use pandas, it can be done in one line:

```
import pandas as pd

dic = {'key1':['v1','v2'], 'key2':['vv','gg']}

pd.DataFrame(dic).T.reset_index().to_csv('myfile.csv', header=False, index=False)
```