# Save an OrderedDict Object to a csv file

Tags: python, ordereddictionary

I have the following object that is an OrderedDict that I would like to export to csv.

```
OrderedDict([('AGG', 0.09888),
             ('BWX', 0.04886),
             ('DBC', 0.06046),
             ('EMB', 0.05899),
             ('HYG', 0.07954),
             ('IEF', 0.09933),
             ('LQD', 0.07909),
             ('MBB', 0.10442),
             ('MUB', 0.09408),
             ('PCY', 0.05172),
             ('RING', 0.0026),
             ('SHM', 0.03761),
             ('SHY', 0.11148),
             ('SPY', 0.07296)])
```

I'm using the .to_csv command but the error message says: "'collections.OrderedDict' object has no attribute 'to_csv'"

Do I need to convert it to a df or an np array?

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40902200/write-python-ordereddict-to-csv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

My first choice will be using `pandas` because of it's simplicity from user-implementation perspective.

```py
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame(d.items()).to_csv('test.csv', index=False)
```

### Alternate Solution

However, ***if for some reason you DO NOT want to use pandas***, then you could use the following implementation.

> **Note**: I am using the `OrderedDict` (`d`) from the **Dummy Data** section below.

#### Create CSV file: `test.csv`

```py
# Create lines
CSV_FILENAME = 'test.csv'
lines = [','.join(list(map(str,items))) for items in d.items()]
# Create csv file
with open(CSV_FILENAME, 'w') as f:
    f.write('\n'.join(lines))
```

#### Check file-output in `test.csv`

```py
# Check if csv file was properly created    
with open(CSV_FILENAME, 'r') as f:
    s = f.read()

print(s)
```

**Output**

```py
# test.csv

AGG,0.09888
BWX,0.04886
DBC,0.06046
EMB,0.05899
HYG,0.07954
IEF,0.09933
LQD,0.07909
MBB,0.10442
MUB,0.09408
PCY,0.05172
RING,0.0026
SHM,0.03761
SHY,0.11148
SPY,0.07296
```

### Dummy Data

```py
from collections import OrderedDict

d = OrderedDict([('AGG', 0.09888),
             ('BWX', 0.04886),
             ('DBC', 0.06046),
             ('EMB', 0.05899),
             ('HYG', 0.07954),
             ('IEF', 0.09933),
             ('LQD', 0.07909),
             ('MBB', 0.10442),
             ('MUB', 0.09408),
             ('PCY', 0.05172),
             ('RING', 0.0026),
             ('SHM', 0.03761),
             ('SHY', 0.11148),
             ('SPY', 0.07296)])
```

Comment: I used the pandas df solution.  Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Use pandas instead

```
d = OrderedDict([('AGG', 0.09888),
             ('BWX', 0.04886),
             ('DBC', 0.06046),
             ('EMB', 0.05899),
             ('HYG', 0.07954),
             ('IEF', 0.09933),
             ('LQD', 0.07909),
             ('MBB', 0.10442),
             ('MUB', 0.09408),
             ('PCY', 0.05172),
             ('RING', 0.0026),
             ('SHM', 0.03761),
             ('SHY', 0.11148),
             ('SPY', 0.07296)])
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient="index").to_csv("data.csv")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just write the CSV file manually:

```
with open('output.csv', 'w') as f:
    for key,val in odict.items():
        f.write('{},{}\n'.format(key, val))
```