# How to save dictionary to csv

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx')
dict_of_region = dict(iter(df.groupby('Region')))
dict_of_region
```

df is a dataframe having 100 rows and 20 columns with a column name region which have 4 regions like say north, south, east, west. By using group by I have made a dictionary which has a key as north and value is dataframe of 20 columns and so on for other regions. Now I want to save these values into a different csv file, like north as one file, south as one file and so on.
How do I do this?

Comment: `to_csv`, give it  a go

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reading/Writing out a dictionary to csv file in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34301088/reading-writing-out-a-dictionary-to-csv-file-in-python)

Comment: didn't work, tried out both before only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for df_name, df in dict_of_region.items():
    df.to_csv(f'{df_name}.csv', index=False)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `for` loop like:

```
for k, v in dict_of_region.items():
    v.to_csv(f'{k}.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: TypeError: to_dict() got an unexpected keyword argument 'index'

Comment: We have to change v.to_dict to v.to_csv then it works. Thanks though!!

Answer (score 0):

You can save it to csv file from data frame itself, without changing it to a dictionary and applying the filter condition in the dataframe itself:

```
list_of_regions = ['NORTH', 'SOUTH', 'WEST', 'EAST']
for REGION_NAME in list_of_regions:
    df.loc[df.Region == REGION_NAME].to_csv(f'{REGION_NAME}.csv', index=False)
```