# Reading and writing out a dictionary to csv file in python (or json)

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv

I have a similar problem to this question
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34301088/reading-writing-out-a-dictionary-to-csv-file-in-python/34301228).
But I got a json file that has to be converted to csv file through python.
The json file is basically multiple python dictionary (example):

```
{
  "d" : {
    'a': 'one',
    'b': 'two',
    'c': 'three'
   },

 "z" : {
    'j': 'eleven',
    'k': 'twenty',
    'l': 'forty'
  }
}
```

I would like to write these dictionaries out to a csv file one after another (in a same column), in the format where each line contains the string key, followed by the string value.

I would also like to be able to read them all back into json file

I have tried to use the solution but I got an error saying that dict_items has no values

```
with open('some.json') as file:
    data = json.load(file)
    data_item = data["d"].items()

    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data_item, orient="index")
    df.to_csv("data.csv")
```

This is the expected output:

[image: expected output]

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "The json file is basically multiple python dictionary (example)", 
where are the commas between the elements of the 'dictionary'?

Comment: show the expect output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `bfill()` to combine all the columns and then just write the first column as the CSV output. This approach should work regardless of how many columns you have, for example:

```
import pandas as pd

with open('some.json') as f_input:
    df = pd.read_json(f_input)

df = df.bfill(axis='columns')
df.iloc[:, 0].to_csv('some.csv', encoding='utf-8', header=False)
```

So if your JSON file looks like:

```json
{
  "d" : {
    "a": "one",
    "b": "two",
    "c": "three"
   },

 "z" : {
    "j": "eleven",
    "k": "twenty",
    "l": "forty"
  },

 "a" : {
    "x": "fifty",
    "y": "sixty",
    "z": "seventy"
  }
}
```

Your CSV file would be:

```
a,one
b,two
c,three
j,eleven
k,twenty
l,forty
x,fifty
y,sixty
z,seventy
```

Comment: How can I read the csv file back to json file? If for example I add new items to the dictionaries and want it to be changed also in the json file

Comment: I suggest you start a separate question. You would need to explain how to assign the keys, as the `d`, `z` and `a` are not written to the CSV file

Comment: I have posted a separate question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70183547/convert-json-file-to-csv-and-vice-versa-using-pandas?noredirect=1#comment124066494_70183547)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to write one of the dictionaries, remove `.items()` and that's it.

Comment: It works but how can I add the 'z' dictionary into the same csv file (below the 'd' dictionary output)?